# how to insert more than 31000 characters into a varchar(64000) field in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I tried to insert more than 31000 characters using insert statement into a varchar(64000) field, but Teradata throws an error as - 3738: String is longer than 31000 characters.

insert into (1,'abc...….12312sdfsdf');--Second field is of length 31090

I can not change the field from varchar(64000) into clob. Please provide a solution to have a second field with 64000 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single character literal cannot exceed 31000 characters, but a character expression or host variable (parameter) can be 64000 bytes. So you can split the text into two literals and concatenate in the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(1,'first part'||'second part');
```

The syntax and details for supplying host variables / parameters would depend on which client you are using.